# Number of bits to count to CHAR_BIT

Tags: c

I have an implementation of a bit vector in C, where I want to avoid division and modulus operations and replace them with (faster) bit operations. So I put bits in bytes (char) and need to index into an array of these and then pull out a bit. My implementation looks like this:

```
#include <limits.h>  // For CHAR_BIT
#include <stdbool.h> // For defintion of bool

// Number of bytes to represent n bits. 
// FIXME: 3 should be log_2(CHAR_BIT).
#define BV_SIZE(n) (((n) >> 3) + 1)

// Remove last byte (divice by CHAR_BIT, i.e. shift by log_2(CHAR_BIT) bits)
// FIXME: 3 should be log_2(CHAR_BIT).
#define BV_CHAR_INDEX(i)  ((i) >> 3)
// Mask out last byte (CHAR_BIT bits)             
#define BV_LAST_CHAR_MASK (CHAR_BIT - 1)
// Extract which bit index we have
#define BV_BIT_INDEX(i)   ((i) & BV_LAST_CHAR_MASK)
// Get the mask for that bit
#define BV_BIT_MASK(i)    (1 << BV_BIT_INDEX(i))

// Getter and setter for bits in vector bv
#define BV_GET_BIT(bv, i)   ((bool)((bv)[BV_CHAR_INDEX(i)] &   BV_BIT_MASK(i)))
#define BV_SET_BIT(bv, i)   ((bv)[BV_CHAR_INDEX(i)] |=  BV_BIT_MASK(i))
#define BV_UNSET_BIT(bv, i) ((bv)[BV_CHAR_INDEX(i)] &= ~BV_BIT_MASK(i))
```

The problem is the two FIXMEs where I shift by 3 bits to get the number of chars to represent n bits and where I get the index into the char array where a bit can be found. I don't much mind division in `BV_SIZE` since I do not allocate bit vectors that often, but I would like to avoid it when indexing into the vector.

Is there a general way to get the number of bits I need to count to `CHAR_BIT`? I have hardwired that there go 8 bits to a `CHAR_BIT`, and on all architectures that I work on that is true, but in case it isn't, can I get this number at compile time?

**EDIT**: I can, of course, use `uint8_t` for my bytes and then define

```
#define BV_BITS_PER_BYTE 8
#define BV_BITS_TO_INDEX_A_BYTE 3
```

and use the former instead of `CHAR_BIT` and the latter instead of 3. I'm still curious if there is a way to get the number of bits I need to count to a byte without building a table for that...?

Comment: `Number of bytes to represent n bits.` what wrong with `#define BV_SIZE(n) (n / CHAR_BIT + n % CHAR_BIT ? 1 : 0)` ?

Comment: Only that this involves one division and one modulus. Those are the operations I want to replace with bit operations.

Comment: The big C compilers today can often optimize divisions and multiplications with powers of two, so it might not be such a big problem as you think. Create a "naive" solution, build with optimizations enabled, and check the generated code. You should also do some benchmarking and measuring before deciding on a method to use.

Comment: What if CHAR_BIT is not 8 ? Why do you want bit operation when compiler will replace by constant expression --', or you could just stock the result, not a big deal to do the operation one time

Comment: @ThomasMailund: Are you saying `n` is a run-time parameter?

Comment: Yes, `n` is a runtime parameter.

Comment: "I want to avoid division and modulus operations and replace them with (faster) bit operations" What makes you think the compiler can't do this for you? Are you using some 10+ years old embedded systems compiler or something?

Comment: And why worry about portability to exotic 16 bit DSP computers? You should spend your energy on making the code safe for mainstream 2's complement computers. By for example fixing integer overflow bugs like `1 << BV_BIT_INDEX(i)`. Overall, these seems like a nonsense task, thanks to the function-like macros it is likely that all you achieve is to introduce numerous safety hazards and create a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude For the compiler to optimise division and modulus to bit-operations it still needs to know the number of bits needed to count to CHAR_BIT. If I need to compute that at runtime I do not get the optimisation.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I just went with the uint8_t solution. It is going to work on all the architectures I work on anyway. I won't have overflows when shifting because I use the vector inside an algorithm that has checked that before it runs.

Comment: @ThomasMailund You _will_ have overflows when shifting, or alternatively your algorithm won't be able to handle setting the MSB. This is because the integer constant `1` is a signed type and you invoke undefined behavior if you do `1 << 31`. Similarly, if these macros are called with all manner of types, you will have implicit type promotion to signed types causing similar bugs.

Comment: @Lundin I see your point. I do not shift by more than CHAR_BIT, but I guess that could be 31 -- although, when using uint8_t it shouldn't be. I guess I can unsign 1 to avoid the issue, right? The macros are only used with ints and `uint8_t*` for `bv`. Anyway, now that I have found a bug in my profiling (see below), I will go back to `/` and `%`.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the two `FIXME`s where I shift by 3 bits to get the number of chars to represent n bits and where I get the index into the char array where a bit can be found.

Stop trying to be clever and just divide by `CHAR_BIT`. The compiler will implement this as a shift if appropriate.

Comment: Well, I get a factor 2-3 speedup from using the shift-mask version compared to the division-modulus version... but, anyway, I can live with using `uint_8` where I know the constants I need.

Comment: @ThomasMailund Is that when compiling with optimizations?

Comment: clang with -O3. I was a bit surprised myself.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I get a speedup of 50% with powers of two, the speedup of 2-3 is when they are not powers of two (and I cannot use bit operations -- I checked both since I also use this indexing with a hash table where the size can be a prime or a power of two).

Comment: Sorry, found a bug in the experiments. The input in my test function was provided at runtime. When I rewrote the experiments to use #define constants I don't see a difference between division and shifting. My bad.